# UIButton border color blurred in my iphone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode6, iphone-6

I want set button border width and color.It works perfectly in my iphone5 simulator.But in my iphone6 simulator not looking good,it becomes blurred effect only on my iphone6 simulator.I am using following code.How to solve this issue?

```
self.But.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[self.But.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f blue:255.0/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor];
```

Comment: The code you've posted by itself looks as if it should run without issues. Are you able to test this on a device? You might find it best to test on an actual device as sometimes the simulator can provide different or unexpected results.

Comment: @DerekLee,In my device i got same result..

Comment: Is it possible for you to include some screenshots of how it renders correctly and incorrectly? Is there any other relevant code that you can include that could help us to determine what the issue may be?

Comment: Did you get any solutions ? I am also facing some problem in my app.

Comment: @raj,i am still facing...